# What happens to unused function return values?

Tags: c++, windows, function, return

If I have a program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int TestIntReturn(int &x, int &y)
{
    x = 1000;
    y = 1000;
    return x+y;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    TestIntReturn(a,b);
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
}
```

what happens to the return value of `TestInReturn(a,b)` since it is unused?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but regarding a matter of style, you might want to reconsider your use of `using namespace std`. For why, please read the C++ FAQ entry [Should I use 'using namespace std' in my code?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/using-namespace-std.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is *discarded*; the expression `TestInReturn(a,b)` is a *discarded-value expression*.  Discarding an `int` has no effect, but discarding a `volatile int` (or any other volatile-qualified type) can have the effect of reading from memory.

Comment: How can that be?  The return value of a function is an rvalue, which means that it doesn't have cv-qualification---any `volatile` (or `const`) is ignored (unless it is a class type).

Comment: @JamesKanze yes, and also a function call isn't one of the expressions causing lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in 5p11.  I was talking about discarded-value expressions in general.

Comment: I know that at one time, there was some discussion of this in the C standards committee: given `int volatile i; i;`, is there an access in the second statement.  I don't know what the final consensus was, but a priori, I would say no.

Comment: @JamesKanze that seems to be covered by the second bullet of 5p11; `i` is an *id-expression* so lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied.

Comment: Could you give more precision.  I can't find a 5p11 (section 5, paragraph 11) in either the C or the C++ standard.  (`i` is clearly an `id-expression`, but `id-expression` doesn't imply lvalue-to-rvalue conversion---or any conversion, as far as I know.)

Comment: @JamesKanze it's 5p10 in n3337.

Comment: Thanks.  I've found it now.  It addresses the issue very explicitly.  Looks like the C++ committee took a different view from what I'd remembered from the C committee discussions (or my memory is bad---that's a very distinct possibility as well).

Answer (score 11):

Since you're talking about Windows, we'll assume an x86 processor.

In this case, the return value will typically be in register EAX. Since you're not using it, that value will simply be ignored, and overwritten the next time some code that happens to write something into EAX executes.

In a fair number of cases, if a function has no other side effects (just takes inputs and returns some result) the compiler will be able to figure out when you're not using the result, and simply not call the function.

In your case, the function has some side effects, so it has to carry out those side effects, but may well elide code to compute the sum. Even if it wasn't elided, it can probably figure out that what's being added are really two constants, so it won't do an actual computation of the result at run-time in any case, just do something like `mov EAX, 2000` to produce the return value.

Answer (score 4):

The return value simply gets discarded. Depending on the exact scenario the optimizer might decide to optimize away the whole function call if there are no observable side effects (which is not the case in your example).

So, upon return from `TestIntReturn`, the function will push the return value on the stack, the caller will then adjust the stack frame accordingly, but won't copy the returned value from the stack into any variable.

Comment: On what architecture will an `int` as return value be on the stack?  On an Intel, it will be in `EAX`; on a Sparc in `o0`.  The code will just ignore the contents of the register.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing - it goes into the ether, and is not stored/used.  The return value itself is an rvalue or temporary; I believe the compiler will optimize even the temporary creation out due to it not actually being used.

Comment: The formal semantics are that the temporary is destructed at the end of the full expression.  Since the temporary is _constructed_ inside the function, and _destructed_ at the call site, the compiler must inline the function it is to eliminate the temporary.

Answer (score 0):

The return value is stored on the stack and popped off when the function returns. Since it is not being assigned to a variable by the caller, it is just discarded when the stack is popped.

Comment: Very few architectures will store the return value on the stack, at least if it is type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody answered correctly - the return value in this case is simply discarded, and in this specific example, you can ignore it.

*However*, if the return value is a pointer to memory allocated inside the function, and you ignore it, you'll have a [memory leak.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)

So some function values you can't just ignore, but in this case - you can.

Comment: Depending on the type of the pointed to object, you may be able to ignore it as well.  I've used objects whose constructor registers the object in a dictionary, where it can later be found.  On the other hand, if the return value is a smart pointer, or any other class type, its destructor will be called.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of primitive types, nothing happens to it.  It is
just ignored.  In the case of class types, the returned object
will be destructed, without anything else happening to it.