# What happens to unused return values?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, return-value

First I did look into this. I found the same question on here but in regards to C++: [What happens to unused function return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096509/what-happens-to-unused-function-return-values)

My interest is in Java (though the thread was indeed interesting).

General consensus was that nothing really happens and if anything gets overridden later. Are there any differences from that thread for java?

(Links would be appreciated as I can imagine what probably happens but would like some proof & detail. Also I'm looking for a bit more depth then "It doesn't get set to a variable")

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Something from the compiler perspective? Because from the programmer perspective "It doesn't get set to a variable" seems to be the best answer.

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question than "what happens"? Is this a question about Java, Java bytecode, or the actual machine code the just in time compiler compiles to?

Comment: What the compiler/JVM actually does in this situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler sees that it is not used and just leaves the value on the (return) stack unassigned aka removes it. If you assign it but not use it, it lives until this references is not longer in use.

See the attached screenshot. Eclipse and a bytecode plugin.

Under L0, you can see that the return of the concat call is stored (ASTORE 1). The same call under L1, which in Java is not used or assigned, is just handled with a POP aka it is removed from the stack and gone.

[image: bytecode of return handling]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh ok thank you very much. Also what is the name of that plugin if you don't mind my asking? I searched Eclipse Marketplace with string "bytecode" and returned no results :(

Answer (score 3):

If we compile the program

```
public class Test {
    static int m() {
        return 42;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        m();
    }
}
```

and then inspect the generated bytecode with

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javap.exe" -verbose Test.class

we see the following for main():

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: invokestatic  #18                 // Method m:()I
         3: pop
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 10: 0
        line 11: 4
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
```

As we can see, the compiler emits a `pop` instruction, which instructs the JVM to discard that value.

In machine code, this means that the JVM is free to reuse the memory location (or cpu register) to hold some other variable.