# What happens to data that it is returned by an API and ignore

Tags: rest, api

I hope you are well, i am not a developer and i wanted to draw from the massive pool of expertise in here. I have an odd ish question that i can not accept the answer that i have been given as it does not add up from a security perspective.

the situation is that our API is passing a token with reference number for payment to a card payment provider which is Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard compliant, we do not want that responsibility hence we contract them. the customer enters all the details (name, card number etc etc) on the contractors site. They have a secure reporting portal that we do the reporting of daily transactions, refunds etc, so there is no need for us to have any data other than a reference number to marry it up with the token sent from us. It transpired earlier today that their API returns not only the token with the unique reference we need but the name, last 4 digits of card, address and other identifiable information, which we do not need or we want to have sight off.

The Contractor's reply was to and i quote "just ignore the data that it is return through the API and you do not need". I asked them what happens to that data a number of times and they did not provide a direct reply they just said other organisations use it that way with no issues...which as you expect have drove me absolutely bazurke.

i have found this 5 year old answer that says that disappears to the ether. I cant accept that data just disappears, insert GDPR concerns here.

[What happens to unused function return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096509/what-happens-to-unused-function-return-values)

Apologies for the rant

TLDR: we sent token with unidentifiable personal information to card payment provider through API, Card Providers API returns name, card, address and other identifiable data. Card Providers response just ignore the information returned from the API you do not need.

thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: How are you accessing this API?  Can you describe in a little more detail what software or websites you use to access this information?  When you say they return card # address and other info, where is this data being returned to?

Comment: @EMcG thank you for the prompt reply, to answer as much as i can on your comment. our website takes, literally only takes the reference number of an invoice that needs to be paid, converts it to a unique reference and passed through the API to the card processor's website that does the processing. Their API should only send us a unique reference number back to our website that we can marry up the customer and the payment.

Answer (score 1):

So since you use a website to contact this API I will try to break down what is occurring.

You enter in a number on your website, which in turn becomes the key reference for the API call to the payment processor.  The processor receives the ref number and grabs info pertaining to that number from their database.  They then send this data as a response to your API call and the data is returned to the website.  Now I am just speculating here but I am guessing your website does not do anything with this data, except display it.  If this is the case the data is sitting in volatile memory, on the server the website is running on.  Volatile memory (RAM) is memory that is not long lived, once space is needed it will be overwritten or if the system is turned off, it will be wiped immediately. Even when this data is in volatile memory it is only used in the context of your session on the website.  Once you leave the page, there is no real way(easy anyway) to get that data back.  It may still exist in RAM, but it is not accessible to anyone anymore and will be destroyed or overwritten once the server realizes it is not being used anymore.

There is a chance however that your website does save the API responses you get back in your own database.  It sounds like this is not the case but I cannot be sure.  But to ultimately answer the question, you can ignore this data and it is not very vulnerable or accessible to the outside world, so you don't have to worry about it getting into the wrong hands in this case.  I hope this helps you some!  Let me know if I can clarify anything for you further!

Answer (score 0):

If no one uses the data, or looks at it, or stores it -- if it's just ignored -- then, yes, it disappears.

More specifically, in the computer that receives it, it's probably written into some space in volatile memory, and then the space is reused and overwritten the next time a response come in. Conceptually, at least.

It's possible that the receiving application has some kind of logs that are writing out data that is received, regardless of whether the app uses it or not, but other than that, without knowing what the app is doing, it's impossible to guess further.

Comment: when you say app do you mean on our end or at the end of the card payment processor? see added comment above if it is any help. once again thank you all for your replies.